# Decompile a Unity game built for Android to find a method reference call

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, reverse-engineering

I use JADX to decompile android apps written in Java/Kotlin to find references to Java/Kotlin method calls (that were not obfuscated).

Is there a way to do the same for Unity code?

Answer (score 0):

There are many resources out there that will help you reversing a unity based Android app. The app might use IL2CPP, it might not. You will have to figure out the details yourself.

[A blog post that gives a general overlook](https://palant.info/2021/02/18/reverse-engineering-a-unity-based-android-game).

Assuming Il2CPP is used, you can dump the binary from memory and then use [Il2CppDumper](https://github.com/Perfare/Il2CppDumper). I never used it but [Cpp2IL](https://github.com/SamboyCoding/Cpp2IL) seems useful too. Lastly if you manage to restore the managed DLL or the game does not use IL2CPP, you can use [dnSpy](https://github.com/dnSpy/dnSpy) to get readable C# source code from a C# application.